# Error al pasar datos a modal con python, flask y javascript

Tags: javascript, python, datatables, flask

estoy tratando de pasar datos de una tabla de bootstrap 5 a un modal con js pero al momento de realizarlo no me muestra los datos y no se que podría pasar.
les dejo mi código de python, html y js

yo creo y mando los datos desde python a html con esta función

```
@classmethod
    def Usuarios_Listar(self, db):
        try:
            cur = db.connection.cursor()
            query_sql = "CALL sp_Usuarios_Listar()"
            cur.execute(query_sql)
            data = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
            
            if data != None:
                user = []
                for row in data:
                    usuario = Usuarios(row[0], row[1], None, row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5])
                    user.append(usuario)
                    
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception(ex)
```

luego en app.py los mando así

```
#Decorador para editar usuarios
@app.route('/edit_user')
@login_required
def edit_user():
    roll = session["id_Rol_Usuarios"]
    if roll == "1":
        lista_user = consultaUsuarios.Usuarios_Listar(db)
        
        return render_template('admin/edit_user.html', users = lista_user)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('logout'))
```

posteriormente en html los muestro de esta manera

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 2rem; margin-bottom: 3rem;">
                    <table id="example" class="table table-dark table-hover" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                                <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                <th scope="col">Rol</th>
                                <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                                <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                                <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for user in users %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.usuario_Usuarios }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.nombre_Usuarios }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.id_Rol_Usuarios }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    {% if user.estado_Usuarios == 1 %}
                                    <label for="">Activado</label>
                                    <div class="form-switch">
                                        <input class="form-check-input sombra" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                                            id="flexSwitchCheckCheckedDisabled" checked disabled>
                                    </div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if user.estado_Usuarios == 0 %}
                                    <label for="">Desactivado</label>
                                    <div class="form-switch">
                                        <input class="form-check-input sombra" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                                            id="flexSwitchCheckDisabled" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                    {% endif %}

                                </td>
                                <td>{{user.fecha_Usuarios}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <!--EDITAR + abre modal Editar usuario-->
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success sombra" style="margin-right: 1rem; margin-bottom: 0.5rem;" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                        data-bs-target="#modal_editar_user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Editar" 
                                        id="btnEditUser" data-idEditSet="hola" data-usuarioEditSet="{{ user.usuario_Usuarios }}" 
                                        data-nombreUsuariosEditSet="{{ user.nombre_Usuarios }}" data-idRolUsuariosEditSet="{{ user.id_Rol_Usuarios }}" 
                                        data-estadoUsuariosEditSet="{{ user.estado_Usuarios }}" data-fechaUsuariosEditSet="{{ user.fecha_Usuarios }}">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-file-pen"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

para poder mandarlos a mi modal utilizo una función de js que los captura y los enviá que es esta

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("click", "#btnEditUser", function () {
            var idUserEdit = $(this).data('idUserEditSet');
            var usuarioEdit = $(this).data('usuarioEditSet');
            var nombreUsuariosEdit = $(this).data('nombreUsuariosEditSet');
            var idRolUsuariosEdit = $(this).data('idRolUsuariosEditSet');
            var estadoUsuariosEdit = $(this).data('estadoUsuariosEditSet');
            var fechaUsuariosEdit = $(this).data('fechaUsuariosEditSet');
            $("#idUserEditGet").val(idUserEdit);
            $("#usuarioEditGet").val(usuarioEdit);
            $("#nombreUsuariosEditGet").val(nombreUsuariosEdit);
            $("#idRolUsuariosEditGet").val(idRolUsuariosEdit);
            $("#estadoUsuariosEditGet").val(estadoUsuariosEdit);
            $("#fechaUsuariosEditGet").val(fechaUsuariosEdit);

        });
    </script>
```

y en mi modal los muestro de esta manera

```
<!-- Modal editar usuarios-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_editar_user" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"
                style="background-color: #147246; color: white; justify-content: center; border: 0;">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel"><b>Editar usuario</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body fondo-negro">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class=" needs-validation" action="/update_user" method="POST" novalidate>
                            
                            <br>
                            <div >
                                <input type="" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                <!--ID-->
                                <input type="" id="idUserEditGet" name="id" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="">
                                <label for="username" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">Usuario o
                                    Correo</label>
                                <input type="text" maxlength="45" class="form-control shadow" id="usuarioEditGet" name="username"
                                    placeholder="usuario o correo" required>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="">
                                <label for="fullname" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">Nombre completo</label>
                                <input type="text" maxlength="45" class="form-control shadow" id="nombreUsuariosEditGet" name="fullname"
                                    placeholder="Nombre completo" required>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="">
                                <label for="roll_user" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">Rol del
                                    usuario</label>
                                <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3 shadow" style="font-size: 12pt;"
                                    id="idRolUsuariosEditGet" name="roll" required>
                                    <option selected disabled>elige...</option>
                                    <option value="administrador">administrador</option>
                                    <option value="comun">comun</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="">
                                <label for="estado_user" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">Estado del
                                    usuario</label>
                                <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3 shadow" style="font-size: 12pt;"
                                    id="estadoUsuariosEditGet" name="estado_user" required>
                                    <option selected disabled>elige...</option>
                                    <option value="1">Activado</option>
                                    <option value="0">Desactivado</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="">
                                <label for="fecha_user" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">Fecha de
                                    ingreso</label>
                                <input type="date" maxlength="" class="form-control shadow" id="fechaUsuariosEditGet" name="fecha_user" required>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 2rem; margin-top: 2rem;">
                                <button class="w-50 btn btn-success sombra" type="submit"><i
                                        class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i> Actualizar</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #147246; border: 0; border: 0;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger sombra" data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="bottom" title="Cerrar"><i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

segun yo esto esta bien y no deveria tener problema ya que me funcionaba hasta que cambie el nombre de las id y variables por uno que se pueda entender mejor. volvi al nombre anteriro pero aun asi no me los muestra y ahora aparecen en blanco.
adjunto foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Solución.

lo que para mi funciono fue cambiar el nombre a las variable de data-nombre

por ejemplo en el valor:

```
data-usuarioEditSet="{{ user.usuario_Usuarios }}"
```

En el código del error no se muestran los resultados por que al parecer existen varios problemas

1- El "data-" al parecer la palabra "edit" es un valor reservado, por lo que no se puede contener en el nombre.
2- no tolera combinación de mayúsculas y minúsculas y tampoco dos guiones medios.
Ejemplo, el "data-" no estar de estas maneras:

```
data-usuarioEditSet=""

data-usuario-Edit-Set=""
```

Lo que si se puede hacer es esto:

```
data-usuarioset=""

data-usuario_set=""
```

por lo que yo procedí a dejar mi botón de esta manera.

```
<!--EDITAR + abre modal Editar usuario-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success sombra" 
  style="margin-right: 1rem; margin-bottom: 0.5rem;" data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#modal_editar_user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Editar" 
  id="btnEditUser" 
  data-edi_id_us="{{ user.id }}"
  data-edi_us_us="{{ user.usuario_Usuarios }}" 
  data-edi_nom_us="{{ user.nombre_Usuarios }}"
  data-edi_id_rol_us="{{ user.id_Rol_Usuarios }}" 
  data-edi_est_us="{{ user.estado_Usuarios }}" 
  data-edi_fech_us="{{ user.fecha_Usuarios }}">
  Editar
</button>
```